# Does defragmenting a hard drive require at least some free space? If so, how much?

Tags: hard-drive, defragment

Question inspired by this gif from wikipedia:

[image]

<sub><sub>(Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defragmentation#/media/File:FragmentationDefragmentation.gif)</sub></sub>

In the gif, the blocks (sectors?) are moved to free space, and rearranged (defragmentation).

Is free space required?

Comment: Why do you want to defrag? Keep your pagefile.sys and hiberfil.sys on a separate partition

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to defragment? Defragmenting helps HDD read times doesn't it?

Comment: Yes - I recommend you set up a 40-50GiB partition for swap and hibernation data, as swap particularly just writes anywhere, ALL over the main volume. It’s the number one fragging culprit. I can provide a link, or you can google. I can tell you why Microsoft went with a file swap model, but SE moderates obscenities. hiberfil.sys will in size not exceed RAM, but pagefile.sys will.

Comment: What OS?  What file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the very article you got the gif:

> To defragment a disk, defragmentation software (also known as a "defragmenter") can only move files around within the free space available. This is an intensive operation and cannot be performed on a filesystem with little or no free space. [wikipedia-defragmentation-mitigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defragmentation#Mitigation)

Windows XP Defrag requires 15% free disc space.

Comment: This is a generally good answer, but I'm curious why you would reference Win XP rather than a more current version.

Comment: Well, I wasn't very attentive. Would you know how much W10 requires?

Comment: Shouldn't that be up to the author of the answer to determine?

Comment: I knew for XP, after I switched to Linux ^^

Answer (score 1):

There are two options for defragmentation. You can do it the Easy Way, or you can do it the Good Way:

1. Keep the data to be moved and defragmented entirely in memory. Essentially you have to read entire files until you free up enough space to then write one back in a continuous block.

   - the upside to this is that it will be faster and not need extra storage on the disk
2. Move the data elsewhere on disk, then move it back when a continuous block large enough is created.

   - this way is a lot slower as data has to be repeatedly read and written somewhere else.

Option 1 potentially does not need extra space on the disk, but is also potentially dangerous.

- While files are being read and deleted the data no longer exists on disk. In the event of a power cut whatever files have been read but not restored to their new location are lost, potentially with catastrophic effects.
- you have no idea how large a buffer you might need to read files. You might have multi gigabyte files that need moving or a lot of tiny files. It needs either the ability to allocate potentially infinite amounts of memory (expanding the page file and making fragmentation *worse*), or use a fixed percentage of memory. If you have a fixed buffer size you could load (and truncate) part of the file to free up space, but you end up in a worse position in that you could have missing *parts* of files in the event of power failure which would arguably be worse than missing the whole file.

Option 2 always guarantees that your data is on disk, especially if you copy first and *then* delete blocks.

So yes, for safe defragmentation without looming threat of catastrophic data loss, you need some disk space free.